# Best implementation for transitionWithView in Navigation Controller when the user tap BACK

Tags: ios6, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uiviewanimation

I have 2 UIViewControllers inside a NavigationController.

The first one, A,  has just an UISearchBar on top of a tableView, as the tableHeader.
The second one, B, has a view in the upper part of the screen (let's call it a custom TableHeader) and a table below this view.

I wanted to simulate the modal transitionFlipFromRight when pushing from UIViewController A to UIViewControllerB and to simulate the modal transitionFlipFromLeft when popping from UIViewController B to UIViewController A when the user tap the navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.

No problem for the push side:

```
UIViewController *vcB = [UIViewController alloc] init];

[self.navigationController pushViewController: vcB animated: NO];

[UIView transitionWithView:self.navigationController.view
           duration:0.8
           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
           animations:nil
           completion:nil];
```

It works as expected.

I have problems implementing the pop, the switch back from UIViewController B to UIViewController A.

I added this code in the UIViewController B:

```
 -(void) viewWillDisappear: (BOOL) animated
 {
  [super viewWilDisappear: NO]
  [UIView transitionWithView:self.navigationController.view
           duration:0.8
           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
           animations:nil
           completion:nil];


 }
```

I can see the flip but I am not satisfied with the result because for a fraction of a second after the switch from B to A I can still see the B custom tableHeader, moved from left border by 10 points.

Should I manage the transition from B to A in viewWillDisappear or I am totally wrong in doing this?
If I am wrong, What is the correct way to handle the pop animation?

Thanks

Nicola

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you try this in your viewWillDisappear itself and check whether this works?

```
UIViewController *vcA = [UIViewController alloc] init];

[[self retain] autorelease];

[self.navigationController pushViewController: vcA animated: NO];

[UIView transitionWithView:self.navigationController.view
       duration:0.8
       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
       animations:nil
       completion:nil];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

This is a tested code. So it works fine. This should help you.